# How to avoid redirecting to login page, when page is refreshed in next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, jwt

I am currently working on user authentication and authorization in next.js. I created a custom authguard hook, and it is working fine. But the problem arises when user refreshes the page after login, it is redirected to login page.

AuthGuard Flow:- If the user is not authenticated it will redirect them to login page and if the user is authenticated it should not redirect them to login when user refreshes the page(But currently it is redirecting to login page after page refresh).

Complete Flow:- There are some protected pages in my project like dashboard, protected, where user can't enter without login. After login, the server sends the access token and refresh token to the client. Access token is stored in memory and refresh token in HTTPS secure cookie. A new access token is sent to the client whenever the user refresh the page.

***How to solve this problem***(Also if you have better approach to work with authorization in next.js then let me know)?

Code to Repo:- https://github.com/Sumukha210/next.js-authentication

```
AuthGuard:-
    import { useRouter } from "next/router";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import useStore from "../context/store";
    
    const useAuthGuard = () => {
      const isAuthenticated = useStore(s => s.isAuthenticated);
      const loading = useStore(s => s.loading);
      const router = useRouter();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!loading && !isAuthenticated) {
          router.replace("/auth/login");
        }
      }, [isAuthenticated, loading]);
    
      const ProtectedComponent: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
        if (loading) {
          return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }
        return <div>{isAuthenticated ? children : <></>}</div>;
      };
    
      return [ProtectedComponent];
    };
    
    export default useAuthGuard;

 store.ts:-

    import create from "zustand";
    import { devtools } from "zustand/middleware";
    
    type roleType = "user" | "admin";
    
    enum AccessLevel {
      USER = "CODE 234",
      EDITOR = "CODE 134",
      ADMIN = "CODE 34",
    }
    
    type useStoreTypes = {
      isAuthenticated: boolean;
      role: roleType;
      accessToken: null | string;
      loading: boolean;
    
      changeRole: (type: roleType) => void;
      setAccessToken: (val: string | null) => void;
      setLoading: (val: boolean) => void;
    };
    
    const useStore = create<useStoreTypes>(
      devtools(
        (set): useStoreTypes => ({
          isAuthenticated: false,
          role: "user",
          accessToken: null,
          loading: false,
    
          changeRole(type) {
            set(() => ({ role: type }));
          },
    
          setAccessToken(val) {
            set(() => ({ accessToken: val, isAuthenticated: val ? true : false }));
          },
    
          setLoading(val) {
            set(() => ({ loading: val }));
          },
        }),
        { name: "authStore" }
      )
    );
    
    export default useStore;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your isLoading & isAuthenticated states are back to their default state whenever you refresh your entire page.

You have several options to do:

1. using localStorage when login & logout

   localStorage.setItem("Authenticated", isAuthenticated);
   localStorage.removeItem("Authenticated");
2. using cookies when login & logout
   document.cookie = 'authenticated=isAuthenticated';
   document.cookie.split(";") to retrieve authenticated information
3. using something like redux-persist to store user state in browser
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But if the state is persisted to local storage, doesn't it hurt my security?. The whole point of storing access token in memory(state) instead of storing it local storage or in cookie is to prevent Xss and XSRF Attack. Is there any other way?

Comment: Your token should be security enough to store in localStorage or some similar mechanism. Taking JWT as an example,  the encryption and your secret when you encode the token should be quite secure if you set expiration time to prevent potential counterfeit behavior. Also you would want to check the validity of your token whenever a user is in your website. Typically, there is no much security issue to worry as a frontend dev except for XSS. XSRF security are usually handled in backend.